# Error opening CA private key when Create the intermediate pair

Tags: openssl

I follow this [tutorial](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/create-the-root-pair.html) to ***Create the root pair*** and ***Create the intermediate pair***.

***Create the root pair*** is fine, but when i try to ***Create the intermediate pair*** it's error at this line:

```
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -extensions v3_intermediate_ca \
      -days 3650 -notext -md sha256 \
      -in intermediate/csr/intermediate.csr.pem \
      -out intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem
```

with error is:

```
Error opening CA private key /root/ca/private/ca.key.pem
140382210524824:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('/root/ca/private/ca.key.pem','r')
140382210524824:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
unable to load CA private key
```

I follow step by step and check so many time but really don't know why. What am i missing? Someone know please give me some advice

Comment: Hey, someone can tell me why :))

Comment: This looks like a file problem.  Make sure that the ca private file exists /root/ca/private/ca.key.pem and that you are allowed to access the file if it does exist.

Comment: It's exists and when I run: **openssl rsa -check -noout -in /root/ca/private/ca.key.pem**, it's show: RSA key ok

Comment: Since the private key path comes from the OpenSSL.cnf file. Check the path in there doesn’t have weird characters or spaces/tabs that is stuffing up the path. Go as far as re-typing in the path to make sure...

Comment: ok, thank you, i will check it

Comment: I found problem, it't wrong path, I edit and it't work fine, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same problem on ubuntu. Did following steps to resolve it:

Copy openssl.cnf to local directory and did the following changes. (Note doble slashes)

fopen_dir       = //home/gl-448//vaayu-dl//keys//vaayu_ca//

private_key     = $fopen_dir//private//cakey.pem